# What is the recommended way to apply styles to an extended React Native component?

Tags: react-native

I have extended the [Text](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html) component in order to have a reusable text component with a custom font.

My custom component should accept the styles passed to it and add the custom font to it.

I'm currently doing this:

**MyText.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    Text,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';


export default class MyText extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const style =
            Object.assign( {},
                StyleSheet.flatten(this.props.style),
                {fontFamily: "My Font"}
            );

        return (
            <Text style={style}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Text>
        );
    }

}
```

While this works as expected, having to flatten the stylesheet every time seems wrong. The above is a trivial example, and I can think of other components on which I could use this pattern. For that reason, I want to make sure I'm not ignoring a more suitable approach.

Comment: You can give an array of styles to components. So in your case the following would work: '<Text style={[this.props.style, customStyle]} {...otherProps}/>' your customStyle would override existing keys on the style object, if you dont want that put customStyle as the first item of the array.

Comment: ive been searching for the above answer for over 30 mins! very simple solution to the case of extending even styled components in react native through a custom component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it depends on how much you would want to customize. In this case , if it is just a different font, it could be something like

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    Text,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';



export default class MyText extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const filteredProps = _.omit(this.props, 'style'); 
        return (
            <Text style={[{fontFamily: "My Font"}, this.props.style]} {...filteredProps} />
        );
    }

}
```